# Cloning a item in a IList using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, list, razor

I have a view model that looks like this

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see it includes an IList of Parts that has a structure like this

```
 public class ItemPartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string PartID { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public float QtyInItem { get; set; }
        public float Qty { get; set; }
        public bool MoveAll { get; set; }
        // This is the additional property to contain what user picks, the action types are harvest/transfer/dispose
        public PartActionType SelectedActionType { get; set; }
    }
```

When the table is displayed the moveAll option in the row is already checked, but if it is unchecked, it clones the row. This is for the purpose of if the user wants to do something like this, Ex// If the there are 4 parts in the item and the moveall option is selected it will perform the selected action for all 4 parts. But if it is not, and the user decides to transfer 2 and dispose of 2 I need to track that. Here is the JavaScript that clones the row

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clonePart input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                //getting closest tr
                var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    // remove cloned row
                    $('#' + Id + 'clone').remove();

                    selector.find(".AllTxt").show();
                    selector.find(".editQty").hide();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
                    //var qtyInItem = $('input[name=Parts['+partId+"].QtyInItem").val()


                    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", (i, n) => n + 'clone');
                    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");
                    var clonedID = Id + "clone";
                    $($clone).append($("<td class= 'addRow' ><a href=\"javascript:add('" + clonedID + "')\">add row</a></td>"));
                    selector.find(".AllTxt").hide();
                    selector.find(".editQty").show();
                    
                }

            });
```

Here is the setup of my row

```
<tr class="tr_clonePart">
   <td>
       @part.PartIDLink
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
       @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
   </td>
   <td style="font-weight:bold">
       <span class="qtyInItem">
           @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
           @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
       </span>
   </td>
   <td>                            
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Parts[i].MoveAll, new {  @class="part-class", data_partId = part.ID })
   </td>                              
   <td>
       <div class="AllTxt">
           @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
       </div>
       <div class="editQty">
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parts[i].Qty)
       </div>
   </td>                            
       @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
           {
               <td>
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType, new { name = "partRadio" })
               </td>
           }
</tr>
```

Here is a picture of my view to help provide more clarity of my situation
[image: view]

In that scenario it would only keep track of the 0.5 of transfer, but I want the list to also have the record of the 0.5 that is being harvested

How can I make it so that it also essentially 'clones' the row in the part list?

Comment: showing some html code or demo  might help .

Comment: @Swati I added in the setup of my row

Comment: Okay from your code i have understood you have a checkbox which is already selected .So, when user unchecked that checkbox then `But if it is not, and the user decides to transfer 2 and dispose of 2 I need to track that...` ? didn't get this ? You mean all rows i.e : everthing inside `tr` you need to clone ?

Comment: say there is 4 parts in my item (qtyInItem). The check box starts off as checked. Meaning that it will perform the selected action for all 4 parts. But say for example the user wanted to do 2 options like transfer 2 parts and dispose of 2 parts (the action types are harvest,transfer,dispose). Right now I can clone the row, but it doesn't affect the Ilist, so the list is currently only tracking what is happening in the original row. But it isn't tracking what happens in the cloned row. Hopefully this makes sense for you, if not let me know and I will try to clarify more @Swati

Comment: @Swati I added in a picture of my view if that helps

Comment: You already have cloned trs so whatever changes made in original rows you need to make same changes in the cloned trs as well  ? Also the input-box for qty can get change so you need to update same to clone qty(tds) . I hope i understood that correctly now ?

Comment: Yes, it clones the table row already. My problem is that if there is a cloned row, I need to also essentially 'clone' that in my IList to reflect it. Because currently, the list will only have the entry for the original row, but it needs to 'insert' the record of the cloned row into the list too. @Swati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218996/discussion-between-swati-and-josh-fontaine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give class to the `cloned` row which will differentiate it from original row and cloned ones .In below code i have use `part_id` to differentiate  between them .Also , i have given `class` to all inputs to easily retrieve its values . Now , to send these values (cloned and original together) i have created `JSON Array` because here value for all inputs will be same only the `quantity` and `actiontype` will change so to save these value i have created `arrays`. Finally you can send the generated `JSON Array` using `ajax` to your backend .

**Demo code** :

```js
$('.tr_clonePart input.part-class').change(function() {
  let Id = $(this).attr('id');
  let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
  //getting closest tr
  var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
  //get original radio 
  var radios_old = selector.find("input[type='radio']:checked");
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    // remove cloned row
    $('.tr_clonePart_' + partId).remove();
    selector.find(".AllTxt").show();
    selector.find(".editQty").hide();
  } else {

    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    //remove class `tr_clonePart` from cloned tr add new class tr_clonePart_parid 
    $clone.removeClass('tr_clonePart').addClass('tr_clonePart_' + partId)
    $tr.after($clone);
    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
    //give unique name to radios
    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", 'clone' + partId);

    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");
    var clonedID = 'tr_clonePart_' + partId;
    $($clone).append($("<td class= 'addRow' ><a href=\"javascript:add('" + clonedID + "')\">add row</a></td>"));
    selector.find(".AllTxt").hide();
    selector.find(".editQty").show();
    //checking if the radio value was check before
    if (radios_old.length == 1) {
      //apply checked
      radios_old.prop('checked', true)
    }

  }

});

//on clicked of button
$("button").click(function() {
  var array = []; //for creating json array
  //looping through trs with class tr_clonePart
  $(".tr_clonePart").each(function() {
    //for storing qtys and radios of cloned and original
    var qtys = []
    var radios_c = [];
    //get infos for various fields
    var p_id = $(this).find("td > a").attr('p-id');
    var mfg = $(this).find("input.part_mfg").val();
    var part_name = $(this).find("input.part_name").val();
    var qty_in_used = $(this).find("input.qty_in_item").val();
    var item = {};
    //add values in json objects
    item["p_id"] = p_id
    item["mfg"] = mfg
    item["part_name"] = part_name
    item["qty_in_used"] = qty_in_used
    //chcking if part-class is checked or not 
    if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox'].part-class").is(':checked')) {

      var move_all = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox'].part-class").val();
      item["move_all"] = move_all
      var radios = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
      radios_c.push(radios) //adding value of radios in array
      item['radios_c'] = radios_c
      var qty = $(this).find("input.qty").val();
      qtys.push(qty) //adding value of qty in array
      item["qty"] = qtys
    } else {
      var qty = $(this).find("input.qty").val();
      qtys.push(qty)
      var radios = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
      radios_c.push(radios)
      //looping through cloned trs 
      $(".tr_clonePart_" + p_id).each(function() {
        item["move_all"] = "false"
        var radios_clones = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
        radios_c.push(radios_clones)
        var qty_clones = $(this).find("input.qty").val();
        qtys.push(qty_clones)
      });
      item['radios_c'] = radios_c
      item['qtys'] = qtys
    }
    //getting other values
    var onhand = $(this).find("input.onhand").val();
    var onwork = $(this).find("input.onwork").val();
    var commited = $(this).find("input.committed").val();
    var fstk = $(this).find("input.fstk").val();
    item["onhand"] = onhand
    item["onwork"] = onwork
    item["commited"] = commited
    item["fstk"] = fstk
    //push json object in array
    array.push(item)

  })
  console.log(array)
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
  //ajax call to save data to backend


})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>
      IGT Part ID
    </th>
    <th>
      MFG ID
    </th>
    <th>
      Part Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Qty used in Item
    </th>
    <th>
      Move All
    </th>
    <th>
      Qty
    </th>
    <th>
      On-hand Qty
    </th>
    <th>
      On Work Order
    </th>
    <th>
      Committed
    </th>
    <th>
      F. Stock
    </th>
    <th style="color:blue">
      Transfer
    </th>
    <th style="color:forestgreen">
      Harvest
    </th>
    <th style="color:red">
      Dispose
    </th>
    <th class="noprint"></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Parts_0__ID" name="Parts[0].ID" type="hidden" value="346" /><input id="Parts_0__PartID" name="Parts[0].PartID" type="hidden"
      value="600601" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemID must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemID field is required." id="Parts_0__ItemID" name="Parts[0].ItemID" type="hidden" value="117" />
    <tr class="tr_clonePart">

      <td>
        <a p-id=346 style='color:#FF00FF;' href='#'>600601</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        S-16706, Uline
        <!--added class to all inputs-->
        <input id="Parts_0__MFGNumber" class="part_mfg" name="Parts[0].MFGNumber" type="hidden" value="S-16706, Uline" />
      </td>
      <td>
        Supply Packing
        <input id="Parts_0__PartName" class="part_name" name="Parts[0].PartName" type="hidden" value="Supply  Packing " />
      </td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">
        <span class="qtyInItem">
1
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QtyInItem must be a number." class="qty_in_item"  data-val-required="The QtyInItem field is required." id="Parts_0__QtyInItem" name="Parts[0].QtyInItem" type="hidden" value="1" />
</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="part-class" data-partId="346" data-val="true" data-val-required="The MoveAll field is required." id="Parts_0__MoveAll" name="Parts[0].MoveAll" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Parts[0].MoveAll" type="hidden"
          value="false" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="AllTxt">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="editQty">
          <input class="text-box single-line qty" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Qty must be a number." data-val-required="The Qty field is required." id="Parts_0__Qty" name="Parts[0].Qty" type="text" value="0" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="onHand">
27
<input data-val="true" class="onhand" data-val-number="The field OnHand must be a number." data-val-required="The OnHand field is required." id="Parts_0__OnHand" name="Parts[0].OnHand" type="hidden" value="27" />
</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="onWorkOrder">
0
<input data-val="true"  class="onwork" data-val-number="The field OnWorkOrder must be a number." data-val-required="The OnWorkOrder field is required." id="Parts_0__OnWorkOrder" name="Parts[0].OnWorkOrder" type="hidden" value="0" />
</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="committed">
93
<input data-val="true"   class="committed" data-val-number="The field Committed must be a number." data-val-required="The Committed field is required." id="Parts_0__Committed" name="Parts[0].Committed" type="hidden" value="93" />
</span>

        <td>
          <span class="fstk">
-66
<input data-val="true"  class="fstk" data-val-number="The field FSTK must be a number." data-val-required="The FSTK field is required." id="Parts_0__FSTK" name="Parts[0].FSTK" type="hidden" value="-66" />
</span>
        </td>


        <td>
          <input checked class="radios" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedActionType field is required." id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Transfer" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" class="radios" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Harvest" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" class="radios" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Dispose" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clonePart">

      <td>
        <a p-id=347 style='color:#FF00FF;' href='#'>600602</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        S-16706, Ulineg
        <input id="Parts_0__MFGNumber" class="part_mfg" name="Parts[0].MFGNumber" type="hidden" value="S-16706, Ulineg" />
      </td>
      <td>
        Packing Carton
        <input id="Parts_0__PartName" class="part_name" name="Parts[0].PartName" type="hidden" value=" Packing Carton" />
      </td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">
        <span class="qtyInItem">
1
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QtyInItem must be a number." class="qty_in_item"  data-val-required="The QtyInItem field is required." id="Parts_0__QtyInItem" name="Parts[0].QtyInItem" type="hidden" value="1" />
</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input checked class="part-class" data-partId="347" data-val="true" data-val-required="The MoveAll field is required." id="Parts_0__MoveAll" name="Parts[0].MoveAll" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Parts[0].MoveAll" type="hidden" value="false"
        />
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="AllTxt">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="editQty">
          <input class="text-box single-line qty" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Qty must be a number." data-val-required="The Qty field is required." id="Parts_0__Qty" name="Parts[1].Qty" type="text" value="0" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="onHand">
2
<input data-val="true" class="onhand" data-val-number="The field OnHand must be a number." data-val-required="The OnHand field is required." id="Parts_0__OnHand" name="Parts[1].OnHand" type="hidden" value="2" />
</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="onWorkOrder">
0
<input data-val="true"  class="onwork" data-val-number="The field OnWorkOrder must be a number." data-val-required="The OnWorkOrder field is required." id="Parts_0__OnWorkOrder" name="Parts[1].OnWorkOrder" type="hidden" value="0" />
</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="committed">
9
<input data-val="true"   class="committed" data-val-number="The field Committed must be a number." data-val-required="The Committed field is required." id="Parts_0__Committed" name="Parts[1].Committed" type="hidden" value="9" />
</span>

        <td>
          <span class="fstk">
-6
<input data-val="true"  class="fstk" data-val-number="The field FSTK must be a number." data-val-required="The FSTK field is required." id="Parts_0__FSTK" name="Parts[1].FSTK" type="hidden" value="-6" />
</span>
        </td>


        <td>
          <input class="radios" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedActionType field is required." id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[1].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Transfer" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input checked="checked" id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" class="radios" name="Parts[1].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Harvest" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" class="radios" name="Parts[1].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Dispose" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-success" style="margin:10px">Click Me ! </button>
```

At backend you just need to change the datatype of `Qty` to array and create new field for `actionType` as array to save the value of inputs and radios .